# react navigation - StacksNavigators in BottomTabsNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

i have a problem in react navigation - what i wanted to do is that every page in the tabNavigator will have the header that i created, so i changed evey screen ( Home, Action, Settings) to a Self stackNavigator and added the header for each.

the problem is that it show me the header only in the HomeStackScreen and in the others i see only white screen...

**Stacks**

```html
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import ActionScreen from '../screens/ActionScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';
import AppHeader from '../components/AppHeader';


export const HomeStackScreen = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
       header: () => <AppHeader />
    }
  }
}));

export const ActionStackScreen = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  Action: {
    screen: ActionScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
       header: () => <AppHeader />
    }
  }
}));

export const SettingsStackScreen = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
       header: () => <AppHeader />
    }
  }
}));
```

**TabBottom**

```html
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";

import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import {HomeStackScreen, ActionStackScreen, SettingsStackScreen} from './HomeStack';


const HomeBottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStackScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name={focused ? "home" : "home-outline"}
            size={32}
            style={{color: '#C60900', marginTop: 5}}
          />
        )
      }
    },
    Action: {
      screen: ActionStackScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name={focused ? "flash" : "flash-outline"}
            size={32}
            style={{color: '#C60900', marginTop: 5}}
          />
        )
      }
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStackScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name={focused ? "settings" : "settings-outline"}
            size={32}
            style={{color: '#C60900', marginTop: 5}}
          />
        )
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#C60900",
      inactiveTintColor: '#C60900',
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 14
      },
      style: {
        borderTopWidth: 0.8,
        borderColor: "gray"
      }
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(HomeBottomTabNavigator);
```

***pictures to see what i see:***

[HomeScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vFY2.png) - **Works Good**

[ActionScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZsbz.png)
[SettingsScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM3hP.png) - **Dosent Work**

Answer (score 0):

You must not create multiple Appcontainers  in your app.
There can only be one appcontainer.

Wrap your parent navigator inside appcontainer
Them make home, action and setting as only stacknavigator

the flow would be 
 appcontainer> bottomNavigator-> [homestack, actionstack, settingStatck]

here is the code ...

```js
export const HomeStackScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
       header: () => <AppHeader />
    }
  }
});

export const ActionStackScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Action: {
    screen: ActionScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
       header: () => <AppHeader />
    }
  }
});

export const SettingsStackScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
       header: () => <AppHeader />
    }
  }
});

//---------------

//Your bottom tab navigator  is fine.
```